# Parsing a xml file into data frame with Python (All columns)

Tags: python, xml, loops, root

I have the following code to convert a xml file into a data frame in Python (And it works!):

```
> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et xtree = et.parse("file.xml") xroot
> = xtree.getroot()
> 
> df_cols = ["column1","column2"] rows = []
> 
> for node in xroot:
>     c1 = node.attrib.get("column1")
>     c2 = node.attrib.get("column2")
> 
> rows.append({"column1": c1, "column2": c2})
> 
> out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
```

How can i made this code works automatically for all columns without writting every of them ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: And it works!)  ? Looks like a strange code format. For what kind of xml does this work?